# BlackBerry Problem with Browsing

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, nokia, httpconnection

i developed an application that access the web through the mobile application using j2me for nokia cellphones but when i tried to run this application on blackberry devices i got a problem with it, no website want to be opened, it just freezes
so can anyone help me pls cos i could not find any solution for it 
these r the lines of code that i'm using in the application

this line i'm using to read something from web

```
hc = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url); dis = hc.openDataInputStream(); 
int dataleft = dis.available(); 
for (int j = 0; j < dataleft; j++) {
     buffer.append((char) dis.read()); 
}
dis.close(); 
hc.close();
```

and this line to open a website

```
this.platformRequest("http://stackoverflow.com/questions");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably running that code (which has some issues... don't depend on available() to be accurate, you should just call read() until it returns -1) on the event thread, which is a big no-no on the BlackBerry. The app is likely trying to prompt the user for permission to make the HTTP request, but since the even thread is blocked it can't do it. There's a pretty good description of what to do and not do on the BlackBerry event thread here:

http://www.thinkingblackberry.com/archives/182

It's also mentioned in the API documentation for HttpConnection:

> This interface performs blocking Input and Output operations. An application will lock if an implementation of this interface opens a connection from within the main event thread. Prevent an application from locking by opening a connection from within a thread that is separate from the main event thread.

The API docs are at:

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html

Comment: so i guess the problem can be solved if i solve the thread problem

Comment: i tried all the thread solutions but seems to be hopeless, so would u plz tell me how can i solve the thread problem ??

Comment: It's really hard to say without seeing any code. But you should definitely make sure that you are calling Connector.open() on a separate thread. You should also be sure to trap exceptions and so on to make sure that the code is working as you expect.

Comment: its working just fine very well with nokia mobiles but i dont know what wrong with blackberry

Comment: Is all your code on a single thread? If so, that's definitely the problem on the BlackBerry.

Comment: try
{
    buffer.setLength(0);
    HttpConnection hc = null;
    DataInputStream dis = null;
    hc = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
    dis = hc.openDataInputStream();
    int dataleft = dis.available();
    for (int j = 0; j < dataleft; j++)
    {
        buffer.append((char) dis.read());
    }
    dis.close();
    hc.close();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    System.err.println("Error while connectiong to API!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Comment: You're not understanding. Are you running that code on a separate thread or not? If you don't understand threads, you should learn about those before doing anything more on the BlackBerry.

Comment: look i'll describe the program for u, first when u open the app it asks for a country and a phone number then i send them to the web page that checks the availability of those data and returns 1 or 0, thats all and if its available when i log into the application there r some buttons that takes me to a web page with opening a web browser

Comment: 1st problme is with sending those data to the web and 2nd problem is when i open the web browser

Comment: yea maybe u r right i should learn some about threads, thank you anyways for your help :)